# How to change app name shown in gallery when sharing image?

Tags: android, android-manifest

My question is simple. I want to change the title of my app shown in the gallery when I share an image to my app. For example, the Title shown for *Google Drive* in the gallery is **Save to drive** and the Google drive app name is **Drive**.
[image: share intent from gallery]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Add custom label to your intent filter: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element

Comment: Your comment helped me. Thank you